# Net::SFTP Transfer Mode (Binary vs Text)

Tags: ruby, sftp, net-sftp

Is there a way using the **Net::SFTP** Library in **Ruby** ([API Link](http://net-ssh.github.com/sftp/v2/api/index.html)) to set the **Transfer Mode to Binary**? I am unforunately on a windows system and am uploading a UTF-8 file to a Unix system. The ruby library apparently using Text as the default Transfer Mode and causing my encoding to get garbled with ANSI. If I can force Binary mode the UTF-8 should remain in tact.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found a workaround.

Before, we were doing something like this:

```
sftp.file.open(filename) do |f|
  f.puts(data)
end
```

We changed this to use a StringIO object, like so:

```
require 'stringio'
io = StringIO.new(data)
sftp.upload!(io, filename)
```

Using the upload! method seems to respect the encoding as it just copies the bytes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am no longer on a windows system, but as best as I can tell, this works! Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!